# Why doesn't zfs list output the real size of a snapshot?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

So I am running low on space on a zfs based backup server and deleted some old backups, but the space on the filesystem wasn't freeing up afterwards.

First guess? There must be some old snapshots lingering around. So I ran:

```
zfs list -t snapshot | grep "pool/backups@"
```

And really there were some:

```
NAME                                USED    AVAIL   MOUNTPOINT
pool/backups@auto-20140118.1656-5y  4.81M   0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140120.0900-5y  270K    0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140121.0901-5y  270K    0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140122.0902-5y  270K    0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140123.0903-5y  270K    0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140124.0904-5y  270K    0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140125.0905-5y  270K    0       0
pool/backups@auto-20140126.0906-5y  270K    0       0
```

But while I would have expected to see a snapshot that has a `USED` size of the ~400G I just deleted, there is no snapshot with a noteworthy size at all.

I did spend some hours trying to find the problem elsewhere, when I finally ran:

```
zfs destroy -nv pool/backups@
```

and the surprising output was:

```
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140118.1656-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140120.0900-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140121.0901-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140122.0902-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140123.0903-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140124.0904-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140125.0905-5y
will destroy pool/backups@auto-20140126.0906-5y
will reclaim 421G
```

So my question here is: Why doesn't `zfs list` display the real size of the snapshots and what should I have done differently to get the real space consumed by the snapshots in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like it's a bug in your version of the `zfs` command.  Maybe check the FreeBSD bug reports.

Almost certainly it's just an output/display bug (I think you'd notice seriously weird behaviour if it was a deeper problem with storage accounting)

[zfsonlinux](http://www.zfsonlinux.org/) 0.6.5.6 on my system correctly displays the amount of space *used by that snapshot* in the USED column:

```
# zfs list -t snapshot -r backup/hosts/kali
NAME                           USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
[...deleted...]
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-24   526M      -  44.1G  -
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-25   162M      -  44.1G  -
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-26   137M      -  44.1G  -
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-27   116M      -  44.1G  -
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-28   195M      -  44.0G  -
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-29   528M      -  44.4G  -
backup/hosts/kali@2016-05-30      0      -  44.5G  -
```

The `backup/hosts/kali` filesystem itself looks like this:

```
# zfs list backup/hosts/kali
NAME                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
backup/hosts/kali  48.5G  4.06T  44.5G  /backup/hosts/kali
```

See `man zfs`, search for `Native Properties` and then `referenced` and/or `used` for more info on exactly what those fields mean for filesystems and for snapshots.

See also the `-o` option of `zfs list`.  You might be able to use that to bypass the bug and get exactly the output you want.

e.g.

```
# zfs list -o space backup/hosts/kali
NAME               AVAIL   USED  USEDSNAP  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  USEDCHILD
backup/hosts/kali  4.06T  48.5G     4.03G   44.5G              0          0
```

BTW, there's no need for piping `zfs list...` into `grep` as in your`zfs list -t snapshot | grep "pool/backups@"` command.  Try `zfs list -t snapshot -r pool/backups` instead.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. `zfs list -o space` really shows the correct value for `USEDSNAP`. `zfs list -t snapshot -r` is indeed also really a lot faster then using `grep` (the system has +10k snapshots).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I got the answer on [r/zfs](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/g7hw4j/why_cant_you_see_the_space_individual_snapshots/).  The issue is that the `USED` column only shows blocks unique to that snapshot.  If blocks are shared amongst multiple snapshots, they aren't listed at all.  This is so that when you delete a snapshot you will get exactly the `USED` space back again, which will be close to zero if the blocks in that snapshot are still used by other snapshots.

As you delete snapshots one by one, eventually you'll end up with only a single snapshot referring to those blocks and suddenly all that space will show up in the `USED` column.

It's not ideal, but I suppose they do have a point - if, in your case, there is 400 GB shared between a bunch of snapshots, but deleting any one of those snapshots won't release any space, how do you display that?

Comment: Some thoughts.

1. There could be a shared used (SUSED) column which shows how much is referenced in total.
2. Perhaps another command could show all the snapshots which share data with a single snapshot.
3. A graphical tool could more easily show which snapshots are reserving space such as a pie chart with snapshot names on the outside referencing parts of the pie.